# Problem facing during training TensorFlow (BatchNormV3 error)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

During the training of the transformer network for machine translation, the GPU showing this error. Why this problem is coming?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Transformer_MC__translation/model.py", line 64, in <module>
    output = model(train, label)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1012, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Transformer_MC__translation\transformer.py", line 36, in call
    enc_src = self.encoder(src, src_mask)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1012, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Transformer_MC__translation\encoder.py", line 23, in call
    output = layer(output, output, output, mask)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1012, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Transformer_MC__translation\transformerblock.py", line 22, in call
    x = self.dropout(self.norm1(attention+query))
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1012, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\normalization.py", line 1293, in call
    outputs, _, _ = nn.fused_batch_norm(
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py", line 1660, in fused_batch_norm
    y, running_mean, running_var, _, _, _ = gen_nn_ops.fused_batch_norm_v3(
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 4255, in fused_batch_norm_v3
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Users\Devanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6862, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cuDNN launch failure : input shape ([1,4928,256,1]) [Op:FusedBatchNormV3]
```

This is the encoder block

```
import tensorflow as tf
from selfattention import SelfAttention
from transformerblock import TransformerBlock

class DecoderBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, head, forward_expansion, dropout):
        super(DecoderBlock, self).__init__()
        self.attention = SelfAttention(embed_size, head)
        self.norm = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_size, head, dropout=dropout, forward_expansion=forward_expansion)
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)

    def call(self, inputs, key, value, src_mask, trg_mask):
        attention = self.attention(inputs, inputs, inputs, trg_mask)
        # skip connection
        query = self.dropout(self.norm(attention + inputs))
        print(query.shape)

        output = self.transformer_block(value, key, query, src_mask)

        return output
```

The output shape of the attention+input is (64, 80, 250) (Batch size, sentance length, vocab size)

Answer (score 1):

Possible attempts you can make to solve the problem. I had this issue once when I tried to use very big batch sizes and solved it by reducing it.

- Reduce the `batch_size` parameter. Increase it gradually (2,4,8,10 etc.)
- Sometimes when such cuDNN internal errors appear, it is due to mismatch in library installations.

Ensure that you correctly installed all the dependencies (TF+CUDNN+CUDA) and also reduce the `batch_size` once you determined your installation was correct.

In your case, I suspect the problem is due to the large batch size.

Comment: Thank you form the answer @Timbus Calin, may be someone found these solutions useful that you have written.

Comment: The problem i was facing is due to another reason. I written down the 2 line of code in the program                                          
                 [ gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=True)
,                  session = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) } ] which causes the error. I think, I was facing the problem of (GPU out of memory) , that's why I applied it in the code. After removing the 2 line of code, the program is running fine.

Comment: Indeed your solution is for TF 1.X, indirectly related to memory issues. Honestly I did not expect that you had TF 1.X. I strongly recommend that you update to TensorFlow 2.

Comment: Thank you for appreciating the solution I wrote, many people solve their problems and do not bother to upvote/accept or answer at all.

Comment: No, its TensorFlow 2.5.

Comment: The interactive session code that you wrote there is for compatibility with TensorFlow 1, see "v1" or "compat".

Comment: I think this is the equivalent (I am not sure) for TF 2.X  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

Comment: just see the encoder block, you well see the syntax of TensorFlow 2.0

Comment: Yes yes, I can see that, I was just saying that specific snippet for tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions() was usable for TF1. Anyways I am happy you solved it.